# UITableViewCell has 15px right margin with section index view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with section index. When section index view appears, the table view cell will always has **15px margin** to the right, screenshot shown below.
[image: Cell With Section Index]

However, when I removed section index, there would be **no margin** to the right:
[image]

What should I do to remove the margin when section index appears?

Comment: When adding the message and phone button to the cell, are you adding them to the cell's `contentView`?

Comment: Not really, it's actually another cell inserted when you select the above cell. So I use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` to add it.

Comment: Do you have any code to share that you think might be where the problem is?

Comment: I've set  `self.tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` so you can see that section header has no margin to the right even section index view appears. But i don't know why cells do have the margin.